# Impute missing data for mixed effects models?

Tags: multiple-regression, mixed-model, missing-data, random-effects-model

Although I will not provide a reference, because I cannot recall where I did read it, I have several times read or heard that missing data is accommodated automatically in mixed models. Can anyone confirm this? The reason for my question is a reviewer asking me about how I handled missing data in a linear mixed model. The data is unbalanced and missing data (for some 10,000 observations) is around 3 to 5% for 5 of the predictors, out of 10 predictors.

My question is: should we impute missing data in mixed models or is this taken care of by the covariance?

Comment: That would depend on the environment and package you are using and its default settings (specify for a more detailed answer if you wish). In general, it is a dangerous solution to accomodate automatically. As to whether we should, it depends on the proportion of missing data (seems ok in this case) and how strongly you believe it is missing completely at random.

Comment: @katya thanks for Your answer. I'm using lme4 package of the R environment. The proportion of missing data is around 0 to 8% for the 12 variables included in the model. I incorporate random effects for patient and follow-up time. I've actually searched Google for this issue and it appears that missing data in mixed models are not that popular topics; is it because it is not an issue?